# When and how did journal publications start to have such an important role in evaluating researchers?

Tags: publications, journals, academic-history, evaluation-criteria

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_laws_of_motion) says that Newton published the laws in 1687 on Principia Mathematica. And in another [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_literature#History) that:

> The first recorded editorial pre-publication peer-review occurred in 1665 by the founding editor of Philosophical Transactions of the Royal Society, Henry Oldenburg

However is unclear to me when and how publishing in highly reputable journals has become so important, in particular for judging a researcher's past research success. (For example, for evaluating researchers for purposes of awarding funding.)

I assume that it all started as a way to filter or deprioritize low quality research proposals or researcher, but that would make for other question maybe. When and how did journals start to have such an important role in science for evaluating researchers?

Comment: Funding doesn't depend on journal qualification at the moment. It's a crutch for the reviewers of the proposed projects to judge the quality of the researchers. I've never seen any grants where a requirement is ">3 publications with IF >5 in the last 24 months" or something like that. So I wouldn't call it a "system" and it certainly wasn't built like that.

Comment: @VonBeche, so If I publish my research on my blog it is as valid as in Nature in the eyes of reviewers of proposed projects? Interesting

Comment: Maybe. But most reviewers will just look at your publication list, see a Nature publication and assume that it's good research because it has been positively reviewed before. Or they will see that you published on your blog only, and assume it's there because you got rejected from every single peer-reviewed journal. Reviewers just don't want / cannot spend time to read everything and judge everything themselves, so they'll always use proxies.

Comment: And I am asking about how that proxy of where do you publish started :D Maybe I didn't even attempt to publish on a journal because I don't have funding.

Comment: I think the premise of this question is off. Getting funding requires a history of research success, and in most fields, publishing in highly regarded journals is evidence of research success (although not the only evidence!) But that is an indirect link; in most cases, there is no explicit publication requirement associated with grant funding.

Comment: The proxy probably started when people were actually needing and getting grants, instead of paying for everything out of their own pockets because they were just rich.

Comment: I agree that the premise behind this question is off, but when reading it what did spring to mind is that it is quite typical in the UK, at least when applying to one of the Research Councils, to list the journals you expect to target with output from the project. IIRC, one of the assessment criteria is dissemination and impact. It seems plausible that if you were to list bad journals, or just posting on your blog, that could affect the score you receive.

Comment: As per comments I corrected the premise, but maybe I should simply ask since when and how did journals start to have such an important role in science.

Comment: As I understand your comment @ff524  except in few cases, even without explicit publication requirement it is *de facto* a requirement see Ian comment.

Comment: "maybe I should simply ask since when and how did journals start to have such an important role in science." - that sounds like a much better question to ask.

Comment: @Ian If your entire "dissemination and impact" plan was to write a blog post, you would be indicating that you have no idea how research works and how research results are disseminated, which would be a valid reason to reject your proposal! There _are_ other ways to show "dissemination and impact" though: partnerships with industry, technology transfer, integrating research into teaching, presenting at and organizing workshops and seminars related to the research, contributing a research tool (e.g. open research infrastructure, computer software, or source code) back to the research community.

Comment: (Of course, for most research it's _also_ important to disseminate the work to other researchers in the usual way for the field, so as to move the field forward. And that means publishing.)

Comment: @Llopis I think what you are really interested in is when journal publications became an important part of evaluating researchers, not just when journals began to be important (e.g. for disseminating research and learning of the latest advancements in the field), so I've edited your question accordingly. Let me know if I got it wrong.

Comment: Might be a good occasion to remind the world of the existence of [History of Science and Mathematics Stack Exchange](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I am interested in how journals gain such momentum, but I do not wish to make this question change every 5 minutes (even if it is wrong, then close and I would ask a new one more on topic hopefully).

Comment: @plan I am more interested in the "Requirements and expectations of academicians" of this site, than on the dates, and relevant people from the historically point of view.

Comment: *Maybe I didn't even attempt to publish on a journal because I don't have funding* Good journals are usually free for authors.

Answer (score 9):

Widespread peer review in journals is a relatively recent phenomenon. Famously, Einstein and Rosen wrote an incorrect paper arguing that gravitational waves don't exist, which was rejected by a reviewer for *Physical Review*. The rejection made Einstein angry, and he wrote:

> Dear Sir,
>
> We (Mr. Rosen and I) had sent you our manuscript for publication and had not authorized you to show it to specialists before it is printed. I see no reason to address the—in any case erroneous—comments of your anonymous expert. On the basis of this incident I prefer to publish the paper elsewhere.
>
> Respectfully,
>
> P.S. Mr. Rosen, who has left for the Soviet Union, has authorized me to represent him in this matter.

This was in 1936, and Einstein had already published many papers by that point. It appears from his response that peer review was not yet common at that time.

(Source: ["Einstein versus the *Physical Review*"](http://scitation.aip.org/content/aip/magazine/physicstoday/article/58/9/10.1063/1.2117822) in *Physics Today*.)

Googling this I stumbled across a [blog post by Michael Nielsen](http://michaelnielsen.org/blog/three-myths-about-scientific-peer-review/) who links to some historical papers on the growth of peer review that may interest you.

Comment: Peer review might have been less rigorous, but clearly people were still publishing papers, books, and treatises, and they thought doing so was important. The question is specifically on the relevance of published material on a researcher's career, not on the state of peer reviewing over times.

Comment: Although interesting, it doesn't explain when or how did the journals  start to be used to evaluate researchers. But thanks for the link to the blog it is interesting to know the origins of peer review